# Do any of the puranas talk about the history of Punjab, sindh, haryana? sapta-sandhu region

Tags: puranas, history, vishnu-purana, kshatriya, kings

We know that this region played a significant role in early vedic period before the establishment of mahajanpadas
But due to lack of sources on indian history
ie lineages of kings, histories of different indian kings was not recorded properly after the vedic age

Due to the religion of aryans moving eastwards, history of north western region is even more scant

Puranas are one of the few sources that may have tales to tell about history of these particular regions
Scholars seem to suggest that vishnu puran was composed in the punjab,haryana region so it may include pre-mauryan memories of that region..
Please suggest resources I want to know more about the north-western hinduism